# Corrupt Enterprise Library 5.0.msi?

Tags: enterprise-library

I just tried to download the installer for Enterprise Library 5.0.  I used the download [link at microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=bcb166f7-dd16-448b-a152-9845760d9b4c).  When I run it, I get the error message that "The cabinet file EnterpriseLibrary.cab required for this operation is corrupt...."  I downloaded twice, got the same error for each.  Is there a workaround (like an alternate download location) or a way to fix this?  Thanks.

Comment: I've tried as well...same error. Did you figure out a workaround? I'm running Windows 7 64-bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just got the same error.  I downloaded it on a seperate computer where it worked.  I copied the MSI from that computer to my main computer where it installed fine.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it had to do with user permissions.  I'm working in a corporate environment, and my administrator rights had expired.  Once I had admin rights again, I had to download the .msi again, but was then able to install it without issue....